# Shiny R: Plotting outputs onto a scatterplot alongside existing data from a csv

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I want to allow users to see what percentile of income they are in. My app takes inputs then runs some calculations to present a new figure. I want to plot both of these outputs onto a scatterplot using ggplot2.

My data is a csv and looks like this:

```
PP  BTI     ATI
1   9710    9660
2   10000   9900
3   10300   10100
4   10600   10400
etc
```

server.R excerpt:

```
#income calculator
incomeFT <- eventReactive(input$updateButton, {
  if (input$incomeNum < input$taxFree) print(input$incomeNum)
  else print ((input$incomeNum-input$taxFree)/100*input$flatIncomeTax)
})

output$incomeFT <- renderPrint({
  incomeFT()
})

#Income Percentile Scatterplot
incomedata <- read.csv("~/Documents/Work/Shiny/Level 7/Shiny Flat Tax/Flat Tax App/data/incomedist.csv")

ranges <- reactiveValues(x = NULL, y = NULL)

output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
  ggplot(incomedata, aes(x = BTI, y = PP)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    coord_cartesian(xlim = ranges$x, ylim = ranges$y)
})

#Brush and zoom on scatterplot
observeEvent(input$plot1_dblclick, {
  brush <- input$plot1_brush
  if (!is.null(brush)) {
    ranges$x <- c(brush$xmin, brush$xmax)
    ranges$y <- c(brush$ymin, brush$ymax)
  }
  else {
    ranges$x <- NULL
    ranges$y <- NULL
  }
})
```

ui.R excerpt:

```
numericInput(inputId = "incomeNum",
                label = "Your annual income:",
                value = 0
    ),


plotOutput("plot1", height = 300,
                        dblclick = "plot1_dblclick",
                        brush = brushOpts(
                          id = "plot1_brush",
                          resetOnNew = TRUE
                        )
             )
```

Apologies if this is a very simple problem. I've searched through stackoverflow, the ggplot2 documentation and the shiny tutorial/documentation without luck.

Do I need to find a way to write the outputs into my csv? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit**: a visual example
[image]

**Edit 2:** sessionInfo()

> sessionInfo()
>   R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10)
>   Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
>   Running under: OS X 10.11.4 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTNzH.png) en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTNzH.png) stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTNzH.png) ggplot2_2.1.0 dplyr_0.4.3   shiny_0.13.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTNzH.png) Rcpp_0.12.4      digest_0.6.9     assertthat_0.1   mime_0.4         plyr_1.8.3       grid_3.2.4       R6_2.1.2
 [8] jsonlite_0.9.19  xtable_1.8-2     gtable_0.2.0     DBI_0.4-1        magrittr_1.5     scales_0.4.0     tools_3.2.4
[15] munsell_0.4.3    httpuv_1.3.3     parallel_3.2.4   rsconnect_0.4.3  colorspace_1.2-6 htmltools_0.3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you want to trigger a change in your dataset when the value of a particular input changes, making your dataset a reactive value. Here is how you might go about doing that. Note that I compute the percentile of the new data point using the entire data up to that point, rather than the original data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

# ui
ui_foo = fluidPage(
  plotOutput(
    "plot_foo"
  ),
  numericInput(inputId = "income", label = "Income: ", value = NULL),
  actionButton("button_click", "Go!")
)

# server
server_foo = shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  react_vals = reactiveValues(
    # simulate some data --> initialize the reactive dataset
    df_foo = data_frame(
      percentile = seq.int(99),
      BTI = sort(rnorm(99))
    )
  )

  # change the data when the button changes
  observeEvent(input$button_click, {
    ecdf_income = ecdf(react_vals$df_foo$BTI)
    react_vals$df_foo = rbind(react_vals$df_foo, 
                 c(percentile = ecdf_income(input$income)*100, 
                   BTI = input$income))
  })

  # make the plot respond to changes in the dataset
  output$plot_foo = renderPlot({
    react_vals$df_foo %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = percentile, y = BTI)) + 
      geom_point() + 
      geom_line() + 
      theme_bw()
  })
})

# run the app
shinyApp(ui = ui_foo, server = server_foo)
```

## Update:

Adding three features to the first answer:

1. The aesthetic of the user-entered points will be different from the original points.
2. The app will now return the computed percentile back to the user.
3. The app will keep track of the user entered points and will return them in the variable `df_foo_updated` when the app is stopped (using the `Done` button).

Here is the code to do this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

# ui
ui_foo = fluidPage(
  plotOutput(
    "plot_foo"
  ),
  numericInput(inputId = "income", label = "Income: ", value = NULL),
  actionButton("button_click", "Update"),
  textOutput("entered_income_percentile"), 
  br(),
  actionButton(inputId = "done", "Done")
)

# server
server_foo = shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  react_vals = reactiveValues(
    # simulate some data --> initialize the reactive dataset
    df_foo = data_frame(
      Percentile = as.numeric(seq.int(99)),
      BTI = sort(rnorm(99)), 
      `Data Type` = "Original"
    )
  )

  # change the data when the button changes
  observeEvent(input$button_click, {
    ecdf_income = ecdf(react_vals$df_foo$BTI)
    react_vals$df_foo = rbind(react_vals$df_foo, 
                              c(Percentile = ecdf_income(input$income)*100, 
                                BTI = input$income, `Data Type` = "User Added"))
    # the percentile of the income entered
    output$entered_income_percentile = renderText({
      req(input$income)
      paste0("The entered income lies in the: ", round(ecdf_income(input$income)*100, 2), " percentile.")
    })

  })

  # make the plot respond to changes in the dataset
  output$plot_foo = renderPlot({
    react_vals$df_foo %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = as.numeric(Percentile), y = as.numeric(BTI), color = `Data Type`, group = `Data Type`)) + 
      geom_point(size = 1.6) + 
      theme_bw() + 
      xlab("Percentile") + ylab("Income")
  })

  # when app is stopped
  observeEvent(input$done, {
    stopApp(react_vals$df_foo)
  })
})

# run the app
app_foo = shinyApp(ui = ui_foo, server = server_foo)
df_foo_updated = runApp(app_foo)
```

Comment: @gizzard You could elaborate as to what you want, and I will see if I can include them in the answer. Three things I would add are to push the computed percentile back to the user, to mark user-entered points in a different color than the points we started with, and to be able to gather up the user-entered points after the app is stopped. These are not terribly hard to achieve.

Comment: The bones of what I need are in your answer, but I'm not at a stage to grasp it.

Looking at r-cookbook's [data input and output](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Data_input_and_output/) pages I've come up with a theory:

Can I write the input to the csv? (Now in long format.)
`PP Income Category
1 9710 BTI
...
99 159000 BTI
1 9660 ATI
...
99 107000 ATI
blank blank User`
Then (somehow) calculate what percentile the input would be in through reference to the rest of the data? I need the plot to display the whole of the data. I've added an image to my orginal post to show what I mean.

Comment: @gizzard I have updated the answer to include the features that you have requested. Please run the second piece of code, and see whether it does what you want. You will need to combine the code from the first answer in case you want the `ATI` variable on the plot as well.

Comment: I'm getting this warning:

`Warning: Error in handlers$add: Key / already in use
Stack trace (innermost first):
    43: handlers$add
    42: handlerManager$addHandler
    41: startApp
    40: runApp
     1: runApp
Error in handlers$add(handler, key, tail) : Key / already in use`

Comment: @gizzard Restart your R session, and clear out all the other variables. In case the issue persists, post your `sessionInfo()`. This seems like a version issue. Also, despite the warning, does the app work?

Comment: The app is not shown, it says Not Found in the viewer panel/browser window.

Comment: @gizzard You are going to have to post your sessionInfo. Also try running this in a fresh R session after updating shiny.

Comment: Noobing hard here. How do I get my sessionInfo? I'm using RStudio by the way.

Comment: @gizzard Just type `sessionInfo()` at the console prompt.

Comment: @gizzard Looked at your `sessionInfo` -- nothing seems out of place. So my suggestion is to just open up a brand new R session and try the code there. If that does not work, then I will take a look again later today.

Comment: Will have a go and report back. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @gizzard Please make sure first to run the code exactly as I have posted it before changing it around, so that you can be sure that my example works.

Comment: The first code you posted runs, still no further with the second and the error.

Comment: @gizzard I have published a Shiny app corresponding to the second version of the code on shinyapps.io [here](https://tchakravarty.shinyapps.io/q_37226473_1414455/). It is published in showcase mode so you can inspect the code and experiment with the app. I am not sure what is going on with your environment that is causing the app to fail, but you should probably ask a separate question about it.

Comment: I just decided to split your code into server.R and ui.R, I removed the last line `# run the app
app_foo = shinyApp(ui = ui_foo, server = server_foo)df_foo_updated = runApp(app_foo)` and it worked. Thanks for your help.